# Conditional Formatting Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

[image]

Hi, every day i have to update an excel file. This includes formatting column B. (see picture above). I haven't found VBA code yet, to geht this kind of formatting via VBA. in the picture you see a subset of formatting rules, there are more. But there is only those three colors, which I have the hex code.

yellow
#9C5700

red
#9C0006

green
#006100

```
' (1) Highlight defined good as green values
With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=2")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With

With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "in Anfrage")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With



' (2) Highlight defined ok as yellow values
With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=1")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With

With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "ok")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With


' (2) Highlight defined bad as red values
With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=3")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With

With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "kritisch")
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With

End Sub
```

I used this code, but i would like to use the hex colors. How do I use those?

Comment: Should I understand that you **only** have a problem with applying of HEX code colors? I prepared my answer before you updated the question posting your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. Formatting the whole column will consume a lot of Excel resources, slows down the process of formulas update and it useless. The above code format only the B:B column having data:

```
Sub SetFormatRngMultiple_Cond()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngF As Range

 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 lastR = ws.Range("B" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rngF = ws.Range("B2:B" & lastR)
 With rngF
        'first condition:
        With .FormatConditions
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=2"
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count)
                .Font.Color = 1137094
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                .SetFirstPriority: .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        
        'second condition:
         With .FormatConditions
                .Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=1"
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count)
                .Font.Color = 5287936
                .Interior.Color = 11854022
                .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        
        'third condition:
         With .FormatConditions
                .Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="OK", TextOperator:=xlContains
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count)
                .Font.Color = 5287936
                .Interior.Color = 11854022
                .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        
        'fourth condition:
         With .FormatConditions
                .Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="kritish", TextOperator:=xlContains
        End With
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.count)
                .Font.Color = vbRed
                .Interior.Color = 14083324
                .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [this Article](https://morsagmon.com/blog/working-with-colors-in-excel-vba/):

> You can assign the color codes to any Color property of any object in either their decimal or hex representation. Precede the Hex value with the &H prefix

However for some reason VBA does swap the first two characters with the last two characters of a hex code, so your Yellow `9C7500` would go into VBA as `00759C`

So, instead of `.Interior.ColorIndex`, use `.Interior.Color` and put in your hex codes with `&H` at the start.
Example:

```
' (1) Highlight defined good as green values
With Range("b:b").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=2")
    .Interior.Color = &H006100
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Color` instead of `.ColorIndex` and you can also use `RGB()` to more easily set the value
so change your code to

```
.Interior.Color = RGB(&H9C,&H57,&H00)
```